# SQL Server 2012: How to recover disk space from indexes named "NULL" with ID 0?

Tags: sql-server, relational-database, database-performance, database-administration

I have inherited an old SQL Server DB which is about 100GB for mysterious reasons. I'm not a DBA...

Looking through the various schema metadata, I found numerous index references using huge (huge in this case) amounts of space (1 over 8GB) but, while the TableName for the index is noted, the index name itself is "NULL" and the index's ID is 0. I assume these must be orphaned indexes that were dropped but never purged?

**How do I purge these dead index files to recover the 12GB of disk space?**

It seems counter intuitive that I would rebuild an index which no longer exists... Is this something DBCC_SHRINKFILE handles?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The first question you should answer - and only you can do this - is why you have some many heap tables. While thinking about that, you can look through  [this link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/sql-server-heaps-and-their-fragmentation/) to understand heaps, how they work, and how you defragment them.

Comment: Wow, so basically heaps are revealing where an index should exist, but doesn't. At least for this collection of 21 heaps which account for 99% of the space. Looks to be dreadfully inefficient. Thank you for this link...